# Mathematical formula to convert lat-lon to Lambert Conformal Conic

Tags: coordinate-system, r, lambert-conformal-conic, formula

I want to manually convert coordinates (latitude-longitude in degree decimals) data into Lambert  Conformal Conic (more precisely, EPSG:3347).  I already know how to use GIS software functions for this (`st_transform` in R, `ogr2ogr` in gdal, using directly QGIS, etc.). All my search online points to those specific functions.

What I need is the actual equation used to do the conversion so I can program my own function in another software (SAS, Excel, etc) that is less GIS friendly.

I've found [this link](https://epsg.io/2278) that refers to [this manual](https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/373-07-02.pdf) which I tried to reproduce in R, with no success.  I'm not even sure it's to good formula.

```
## The coordinates to reproject
coo = data.frame(lat=c(46.313503, 44.336374, 50.174041, 50.955616, 48.221700), 
                 lon=c(-72.663290, -77.936728, -100.085165, -124.870320, -56.842978))

lat = coo$lat *pi / 180
lon = coo$lon *pi / 180
```

Then extract the information about the projection I want.

```
sf::st_crs(3347)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: EPSG:3347 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4269]],
    CONVERSION["Statistics Canada Lambert",
        METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",63.390675,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-91.8666666666667,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",49,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",77,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",6200000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",3000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Topographic mapping (small scale)."],
        AREA["Canada - onshore and offshore - Alberta; British Columbia; Manitoba; New Brunswick; Newfoundland and Labrador; Northwest Territories; Nova Scotia; Nunavut; Ontario; Prince Edward Island; Quebec; Saskatchewan; Yukon."],
        BBOX[38.21,-141.01,86.46,-40.73]],
    ID["EPSG",3347]]
```

Which we transform into R variables and transform in Radian instead of degree

```
lat1 = 49 * pi / 180
lat2 = 77 * pi / 180
latF = 63.390675 * pi / 180  # is it the latitude of the false origin?  not sure.
lon0 = -91.8666666666667 * pi / 180   # Not sure about this one.
EF = 6200000
NF = 3000000
```

Other variables I need to extract.  Their description was at page 6 of the manual cited above.

```
a = 6378137
f = 1 / 298.257222101
e = sqrt(2*f - f^2)
```

Then, we adapt the formula in the website

```
m1 = cos(lat1)/(1 - e^2 * sin(lat1)^2)^0.5   #  for m1, lat1, and m2, lat2 where lat1 and lat2 are the latitudes of the two standard parallels.
m2 = cos(lat2)/(1 - e^2 * sin(lat2)^2)^0.5


t1  = tan(pi/4 - lat1/2)/((1 - e * sin(lat1))/(1 + e * sin(lat1)))^(e^2)  # for t1, t2, tF and t using lat1, lat2, latF and lat respectively.
t2  = tan(pi/4 - lat2/2)/((1 - e * sin(lat2))/(1 + e * sin(lat2)))^(e^2)
tF  = tan(pi/4 - latF/2)/((1 - e * sin(latF))/(1 + e * sin(latF)))^(e^2)
t  = tan(pi/4 - lat/2)/((1 - e * sin(lat))/(1 + e * sin(lat)))^(e^2)
```

I'm not sure I'm using the right `latF` and `lat`

Then:

```
n = (log(m1) - log(m2))/(log(t1) - log(t2))
FF = m1/(n * t1^n)

r =  a * FF * t^n       #  for rF and r, where rF is the radius of the parallel of latitude of the false origin.
rF =  a * FF * tF^n

theta = n * (lon - lon0)
```

Here, I'm confuse about `lon0` is it the Longitude of false origin? And `lon` is it the lon I want to convert?

Finally:

```
E = EF + r * sin(theta)
N = NF + rF - r * cos(theta)
```

Running this produce:

```
cbind(E, N)
           E       N
[1,] 7673386 1349263
[2,] 7325110 1025063
[3,] 5617116 1594762
[4,] 3999380 2227177
[5,] 8680877 2039659
```

If I compare to what `st_transform` gives me:

```
sf::st_as_sf(coo, coords = c("lon", "lat"), remove=F, crs = st_crs(4326)) |> 
  sf::st_transform(st_crs(3347)) |> 
  sf::st_coordinates()
           X       Y
[1,] 7673199 1352744
[2,] 7324899 1029094
[3,] 5617097 1596987
[4,] 3999454 2229785
[5,] 8680546 2043038
```

I'm not quite there yet.  It's close, but not the same.

In summary, what is the mathematical procedure to convert degree-decimals coordinates to lcc.  why doesn't the process I did is not producing similar values than `st_transform`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've figured it out.

I had the right formula.  To validate that, the projection wkt gives:

```
METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
```

Which fits with the [manual](https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/373-07-02.pdf) at page 19

Than, I validated my equations with their example (which is projection EPSG:32040) to figure that I used `e^2` instead of `e/2` in my `t` calculation (dumb, I know).   Changing this fixed my problem.

The final script in case somebody wants to reproduce this:

```
## The coordinates to reproject
coo = data.frame(lat=c(46.313503, 44.336374, 50.174041, 50.955616, 48.221700), 
                 lon=c(-72.663290, -77.936728, -100.085165, -124.870320, -56.842978))

lat = coo$lat *pi / 180
lon = coo$lon *pi / 180

## The information about the wanted projection
sf::st_crs(3347)

## Which we transform into the variables and transform in Radian instead of degree
lat1 = 49 * pi / 180
lat2 = 77 * pi / 180
latF = 63.390675 * pi / 180  
lon0 = -91.8666666666667 * pi / 180
EF = 6200000
NF = 3000000

a = 6378137
f = 1 / 298.257222101
e = sqrt(2*f - f^2)

## Adaption of the formula in the website
m1 = cos(lat1)/(1 - e^2 * sin(lat1)^2)^0.5   #  for m1, lat1, and m2, lat2 where lat1 and lat2 are the latitudes of the two standard parallels.
m2 = cos(lat2)/(1 - e^2 * sin(lat2)^2)^0.5


t1  = tan(pi/4 - lat1/2)/((1 - e * sin(lat1))/(1 + e * sin(lat1)))^(e/2)  # for t1, t2, tF and t using lat1, lat2, latF and lat respectively.
t2  = tan(pi/4 - lat2/2)/((1 - e * sin(lat2))/(1 + e * sin(lat2)))^(e/2)
tF  = tan(pi/4 - latF/2)/((1 - e * sin(latF))/(1 + e * sin(latF)))^(e/2)
t  = tan(pi/4 - lat/2)/((1 - e * sin(lat))/(1 + e * sin(lat)))^(e/2)


n = (log(m1) - log(m2))/(log(t1) - log(t2))
FF = m1/(n * t1^n)
r =  a * FF * t^n       #  for rF and r, where rF is the radius of the parallel of latitude of the false origin.
rF =  a * FF * tF^n

theta = n * (lon - lon0)


E = EF + r * sin(theta)
N = NF + rF - r * cos(theta)


cbind(E, N)

sf::st_as_sf(coo, coords = c("lon", "lat"), remove=F, crs = st_crs(4326)) |> 
  sf::st_transform(st_crs(3347)) |> 
  sf::st_coordinates()
```